# Slider not visible in PHP but in HTML works

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress

I am making a shortcode of a slider that shows my WP featured posts and that has the possibility to open the details of each post through a hidden div. The slider is based on this one from w3schools (from which you can see the code and test online from this address: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow

The problem is that the slider is only visible in php once I click the next arrow and from there it works correctly. I don't know why, since in HTML it works fine.

The error apppears: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined in

```
      slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
```

**My CSS:**

```
#slider {
    width: 70%;
    
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.slide {display: none;}
```

**My PHP:**

```
   <?php $query = new WP_Query( $args );

   ob_start();?>

   <div id="slider" class="slider">
   <div class="arrows">
   <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
   <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a></div>



        <?php
        while( $query->have_posts() ) :
        $query->the_post(); 
        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post- 
        >ID), '');
        $featuredID = get_post_thumbnail_id();?>

        <div class="slide fade" id="slide">
        <h2 class="zz-sc-jscss"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        By <?php the_author(); ?> on <?php echo get_the_date( 'l, F d, Y' ); 
       ?>
      <?php echo the_post_thumbnail();?>
   <?php 
   echo "<div"; echo ' class="n"'; echo "id=".$featuredID.">";
   $info = $featuredID;echo "</div>";
     
    ?> <div class="open">
  <?php echo get_post_field('post_content', $post->ID);?>
  <span class="cerrar">X</span></div></div>

   
<?php endwhile;

    wp_reset_postdata();

    return ob_get_clean();
  }
```

**My JS:**

```
 var slideIndex = 1;
 showSlides(slideIndex);

 // Next/previous controls
  function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
 }

  // Thumbnail image controls
  function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

 function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in the "slider" div, it does not seem to be closed. Also try moving it after the slide generation loop.

```
<div id="slider" class="slider"></div> <--missing
<div class="arrows">
   <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
   <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
```